# Listing buckets in cloud storage project using PHP API

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to list out all (some, even) of the buckets in my storage project. If I know the name of a bucket, the "bucket" function will get the bucket. But I can't use "buckets" to list the buckets in my project:

```
$client = new StorageClient(
                             [
                              'projectId' => <my project id>,
                              'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(<my json file>))
                             ]
                           );

$bucket_name = 'idx-mls-info-gs-ihouseprd.com';
$one_bucket = $client->bucket( $bucket_name );
print "GOT BUCKET: " . $one_bucket->name() . "\n";
// NOTE: this works


$prefix = 'idx-';
print "Getting buckets (prefix: $prefix)\n";
            $buckets = $client->buckets( ['prefix' => $prefix] );
            foreach ( $buckets as $bucket )
            {
                printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
            }
print "done with buckets"
// THIS DOES NOTHING
```

My service account has the "Storage Admin" role. I am perplexed.
NOTE: I am using PHP 5.6, in case that matters. Composer didn't have a problem installing the GCS library, so I assumed that was ok.

Ok, so I must be missing something. Using my test case of getting a single bucket, I have then used $one_bucket->object(), and successfully gotten an object. But if I try $one_bucket->objects(), I again get nothing. So the multiple case for entities in the GCS is not working for me, whether buckets or objects. Perhaps that's a clue.

Further information:
There is an exception when hitting the iterator (foreach $buckets as $bucket):

exception 'Exception' with message 'exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '4096:Argument 2 passed to Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader::makeCredentials() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/httpd/idxv3/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapperTrait.php on line 158 and defined in /home/httpd/idxv3/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php on line 135' in /home/httpd/idxv3/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:362

Not sure why the authentication is causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the problem was/is. It is in the creation of the storage client. My call the json_decode was missing a parameter. As in my original code, what gets passed into the constructor is a stdClass Object, which is not liked down in the depths of the code. Adding ", true" to the call to json_decode, what gets passed in is then an array, which is desired:

```
$client = new StorageClient(
                         [
                          'projectId' => <my project id>,
                          'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(<my json file>), true)
                         ]
                       );
```

This fixes the problems I was having. Not sure why I didn't get errors earlier on, like in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#storage-list-buckets-php) for your first question and I hope this helps guide you. It describes how to list the buckets in your project.

Comment: Thanks, but I have looked at that, and it didn't help. If you look at the PHP code sample there, it is functionally identical to what I have (and the COMPLETELY ignore constructor parameters, specifically for authentication). The frustrating part is the $client->bucket() works as advertised, but $client->buckets() doesn't seem to.